How to pass the value of a property to a click handler callback?
I'm new to rust (and yew) and I've built some components, but I guess I don't fully understand the component lifecycle yet or rust lifetimes (though I've read through the docs and this SO answer). I have a component which takes a string as a property. The component renders a button that displays that string and passes that string to its onclick handler. If the string is empty, it should default to a provided default. All macros are from the yew framework. I'm running into the following compiler error output:
2024-06-04T16:01:07.169827Z  INFO  Starting trunk 0.20.1
2024-06-04T16:01:07.262038Z  INFO  starting build
   Compiling trunk-template v0.1.0 (/Users/micah/dev/col)
error[E0425]: cannot find value `key` in this scope
  --> src/user_components.rs:50:44
   |
50 |                 move |_| handle_click.emit(key.as_str() )
   |                                            ^^^ not found in this scope

error[E0425]: cannot find value `key` in this scope
  --> src/user_components.rs:53:34
   |
53 |             {format!("Clear {}", key )}
   |                                  ^^^ not found in this scope

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0425`.
error: could not compile `trunk-template` (bin "trunk-template") due to 2 previous errors
2024-06-04T16:01:08.587588Z ERROR ❌ error
error from build pipeline

Caused by:
    0: HTML build pipeline failed (1 errors), showing first
    1: error from asset pipeline
    2: running cargo build
    3: error during cargo build execution
    4: cargo call to executable 'cargo' with args: '["build", "--target=wasm32-unknown-unknown", "--manifest-path", "/Users/micah/dev/col/Cargo.toml"]' returned a bad status: exit status: 101
2024-06-04T16:01:08.587904Z  INFO  serving static assets at -> /
2024-06-04T16:01:08.588040Z  INFO  server listening at:
2024-06-04T16:01:08.588045Z  INFO      http://127.0.0.1:9390/
2024-06-04T16:01:08.588048Z  INFO      http://[::1]:9390/

I think I understand why, but not how to fix it (new to rust).
fn create_storage_default() -> AttrValue {
    AttrValue::from( ALL_STORAGE )
}
#[derive(Properties, PartialEq)]
pub struct ClearProps {
    #[prop_or_else( create_storage_default )]
    pub key: AttrValue,
}
const ALL_STORAGE: &str = "all storage";

#[function_component(ClearKey)]
pub fn clear_storage(props: &ClearProps) -> Html {

    let key_string = props.key.clone();

    let handle_click = Callback::from( move |key: &str| {
        match key{
            ALL_STORAGE => LocalStorage::clear(),
            _ => LocalStorage::delete(key)
        }
    } );

    html! {
        <button
            onclick={
                let handle_click = handle_click.clone();
                move |_| handle_click.emit(key.as_str() )
                }
        >
            {format!("Clear {}", key )}
        </button>
    }
}    


Please edit your question to include the complete error output from the compiler.

You haven't included the full error message and the code in question is under a macro (so really anything can happen there), but the closure move |_| handle_click.emit(key.as_str()) moves from key and then you use key again in format!("Clear {}", key ). You could for example clone the key into the closure, but its not clear what you want to do here (let key = key.clone; move |_| handle_click.emit(key.as_str() ))

@user2407038, I have updated it as per your request/suggestion. Any ideas?

Sorry, you still have not included the full error message. You have truncated all the important information present in the error. When you get output from the compiler, copy paste the ENTIRE output, including line numbers, file paths, literally every single character between the last command you enter, and the final character the compiler spits out. Also you have not updated as per my suggestion, you applied a totally different change, please try it again and read closely - my suggested fix is NOT equivalent to the one you have applied.

Thank you, @user2407038. I've undone my attempt at following your guidance and included the entirety of the compile results provided. I believe I would like to clone the key into the closure, but I'm still unclear on the Yew component lifecycle, so I'm not positive. Your help is appreciated.

...I can't even tell what you're trying to do here? You've got a let binding inside a HTML property? The key variable is a parameter to the callback, not clear why you'd expect it to be in scope outside that callback? Why are you calling .emit on your handler callback? Huh? The closure should already have access to key_string (which is otherwise unused?)?

You need to define key somehow. Replace move |_| handle_click ... with let key = key_string.clone() ; move |_| handle_click ...  and replace format!( ... key ...) with format!( ... key_string ...)
